# Помогите перестроить код с использованием Promise

Tags: node.js, promise

Не судите строго, только начинаю изучение Node.js и с промисами до этого не сталкивался.

Есть вот такой код. Копирует содержимое одной папки в папку, которую создает.

Много колбеков, я хочу перестроить с помощью промисов в виде цепочек `then`

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const _copyDirectory = (input, output) => {
    fs.mkdir(output, err => {

        if (err) return console.error(err);

        fs.readdir(input, (err, files) => {

            if (err) console.log('Ошибка чтения каталога');

            files.forEach(file => {
                let newInput = path.join(input, file);
                let newOutput = path.join(output, file);

                fs.stat(newInput, (err, stats) => {
                    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                        _copyDirectory(newInput, newOutput);
                    }
                    if (stats.isFile()) {
                        console.log(file, 'isFile!');

                        const rs = fs.createReadStream(newInput);
                        const ws = fs.createWriteStream(newOutput);
                        rs.pipe(ws);
                    }
                });
            })
        });
    });
};


const copyDirectory = (input, output) => {
    _copyDirectory(input, output);

};

copyDirectory(path.join(__dirname, 'savedData'), path.join(__dirname, 'in'));
```

Но у меня получилось по виду почти то же самое, и не рабочее.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const _copyDirectory = (input, output) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        fs.mkdir(output, err =>
            err ? reject(err) : resolve({input, output})
        )
    );

const _readDir = ({input, output}) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        fs.readdir(input, (err, files) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            files.forEach(file => {
                let input = path.join(input, file);
                let output = path.join(output, file);

                resolve({input, output});

            })
        }
    ));

const copyDirectory = (input, output) => {
    _copyDirectory(input, output)
        .then(({input, output}) => {
            _readDir(input, output)
                .then(({input, output}) =>
                    fs.stat(input, (err, stats) => {
                    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                        _copyDirectory(input, output);
                    }
                    if (stats.isFile()) {

                        const rs = fs.createReadStream(input);
                        const ws = fs.createWriteStream(output);
                        rs.pipe(ws);
                    }
                })
        )
    });

};

copyDirectory(path.join(__dirname, 'savedData'), path.join(__dirname, 'in'));
```

Еще я пробовал с помощью модуля `util.promisify`, но выглядит так же запутанно:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const util = require('util');
const stat = util.promisify(fs.stat);
const readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);
const mkdir = util.promisify(fs.mkdir);

const _copyDirectory = (input, output) => {
    mkdir(output)
        .then(() => {
            readdir(input)
                .then(files => {
                    files.forEach(file => {
                        let newInput = path.join(input, file);
                        let newOutput = path.join(output, file);

                        stat(newInput)
                            .then(stats => {
                                if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                                    _copyDirectory(newInput, newOutput);
                                }
                                if (stats.isFile()) {
                                    console.log(file, 'isFile!');

                                    const rs = fs.createReadStream(newInput);
                                    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(newOutput);
                                    rs.pipe(ws);
                                }
                            })
                            .catch(e => console.error(e));

                    })

                })
                .catch(e => console.error(e));

        })
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
};

const copyDirectory = (input, output) => {
    _copyDirectory(input, output);

};

copyDirectory(path.join(__dirname, 'savedData'), path.join(__dirname, 'in'));
```

Вообще можно данный код привести к виду:

```
copyDirectory(path.join(__dirname, 'savedData'), path.join(__dirname, 'in'))
    .then(dir => readdir(dir))
    .then(files => files.forEach(file => stat(file)))
    .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Что-то вроде такого, вместо того неразборчивого кода. Спасибо!

Comment: в ноде уже давно есть [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

Comment: ну и вот что... для твоей задачи вполне можно использовать promisify вместе с await, аккуратным Promise.all и обязательным try/catch для отлова исключений

Comment: Можно вместо `fs` использовать модуль [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra). Содержит все те же функции, но возвращают они промисы. Ну и дополнительно содержит еще и функцию `copy` :)

Comment: @norbornen Added in: v8.0.0. У нас, к примеру, v4 используется :D